# Can I access Qt signals/slots of objects out of scope?

Tags: c++, qt, scope, signals-slots

Do the Qt signals/slots follow the scope of native C++?

Let's say I have the following classes: *House, Kitchen, Cellar, Stove* and *Shelf*.

```
class House   {Kitchen kitchen, Cellar cellar;};
class Kitchen {Stove stove;};
class Cellar  {Shelf shelf;};
```

Now I want to send a signal from the shelf in the cellar to the stove in the kitchen. Is the only way to do this by connecting a signal from the shelf to the cellar and a slot from kitchen to the stove and then in house connecting cellar and kitchen? Or is there a way to do this directly?

I have a class that needs to communicate with a user interface and I wonder if I need to "proxy" all the various signals/slots through intermediate classes. Or is this an indicator of bad design?

Comment: If someone has answered your question with an answer that has helped you, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the connection in any method of House, as there you can access both objects. The "connector" must be able to access both sender and receiver, at compile time, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to just link a signal from the Shelf instance to the Stove instance

in House,

`connect(cellar->shelf,SIGNAL(signalHere()),kitchen->stove,SLOT(slotHere()));`

just make sure that `shelf` and `stove` are public variables in `Kitchen` and `Cellar` and you'll be set

Comment: @problemofficer: He answered your question "Is there a way to do this directly?".  Yes, you can do it directly, by making the subobjects accessible.  You can do that by making them public, by declaring friend classes, by writing a function that returns a pointer or reference, etc.

Comment: @problemofficer: Since shelf and stove are not public, you have to do more to setup the connection. You would need to setup a connection of 2 signals, one from a signal in house to a signal in kitchen and one from that signal in kitchen to a slot in stove. Same for shelf and cellar. An example... House `connect(this,SIGNAL(recievedSignalFromCellar()),kitchen,SIGNAL(send2Stove()));`   Kitchen  `connect(this,SIGNAL(send2Stove()),shelf,SLOT(passedThroughKitchen()));`

Comment: the whole chain would be a series of connections Signal(shelf)->signal(cellar)->signal(house)->signal(kitchen)->slot(stove). Its just one way of MANY to do it...

Answer (score 1):

You cant use signals/slots on classes which are no QObjects, so no, your example wont work whatsoever.

You can circumvent the encapsulation if you initilaize the child objects with their parent object, so you can do **dirty** tricks like: `connect(this->shelf, SIGNAL(signalHere()), kitchen->children()[0], SLOT(aStoveSlot()))`. however this will only work if the first child of Kitchen is really a Stove... so since this is a obvious dependency, you should make this visible by making stove public, or by adding a stove accessor method.

Comment: It was merely an example. The actual class would inherit QObject. Thanks for the dirty trick though.

Comment: Still, I think this clarification is important.